# Enforce exclusive order of four processes using semaphores

Tags: c, unix, ipc

I am on the learning curve of C and its capabilities. Below I have tried to create 4 individual programs where the execution is always in order (program 0,1,2,3).

About the program 
Program #0 is always executed (called) first, it also creates semid's 
Program #1 can ONLY be executed if Program #0 has ran 
Program #2 can ONLY be executed if Program #1 has ran 
Program #3 can ONLY be executed if Program #2 has ran

What Do I Need? 
Since, I am a beginner I thought an expert's knowledge on creating a better design or code structuring would help me.

Program Call 
./prog0 && ./prog1 && ./prog2 && ./prog3

### Program #0

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h> 
#include <sys/ipc.h> 
#include <sys/sem.h>

int
main ( )
{
    int semid;
    key_t key;
    union semun arg;

    key = ftok("program0.c", 'a');
    semid = semget(key, 3, 0666 | IPC_CREAT);
    if ( semid < 0 )
    {
        perror("Could Not Created The Requested Semaphore");
        exit(1);
    }
    arg.val = 1;
    semctl(semid, 0, SETVAL, arg);
    arg.val = 0;
    semctl(semid, 1, SETVAL, arg);
    semctl(semid, 2, SETVAL, arg);
    printf("Executing process #0.\n");
    return 0;
}
```

### Program #1

```
int
main ( )
{
    int semid, key;
    union semun arg;
    key = ftok("program0.c", 'a');
    semid = semget(key, 3, 0666 | IPC_CREAT);
    if ( semid < 0 )
    {
        perror("Could Not Created The Requested Semaphore");
        exit(1);
    }
    if ( semctl(semid, 0, GETVAL, 0) != 1 )
    {
        semctl(semid, 0, IPC_RMID);
        exit(1);
    }
    printf("Executing process #1.\n");
    arg.val = 0;
    semctl(semid, 0, SETVAL, arg);
    arg.val++;
    semctl(semid, 1, SETVAL, arg);
    return 0;
}
```

### Program #2

```
int
main ( )
{
    int semid, key;
    union semun arg;
    key = ftok("program0.c", 'a');
    semid = semget(key, 3, 0666 | IPC_CREAT);
    if ( semid < 0 )
    {
        perror("Could Not Created The Requested Semaphore");
        exit(1);
    }
    if ( semctl(semid, 1, GETVAL, 0) != 1 )
    {
        semctl(semid, 0, IPC_RMID);
        exit(1);
    }
    printf("Executing process #2.\n");
    arg.val = 0;
    semctl(semid, 1, SETVAL, arg);
    arg.val++;
    semctl(semid, 2, SETVAL, arg);
    return 0;
}
```

### Program #3

```
int
main ( )
{
    int semid, key;
    key = ftok("program0.c", 'a');
    semid = semget(key, 3, 0666 | IPC_CREAT);
    if ( semid < 0 )
    {
        perror("Could Not Created The Requested Semaphore");
        exit(1);
    }
    if ( semctl(semid, 2, GETVAL, 0) != 1 )
    {
        semctl(semid, 0, IPC_RMID);
        exit(1);
    }
    printf("Executing process #3.\n");
    semctl(semid, 0, IPC_RMID);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Programs exit instead of wait

Right now, your programs check their semaphore, but if they don't find the value they are expecting, they exit instead of wait.  I think that you should modify your programs to wait until the previous program signals them.  You would need to make the following modifications:

1. In program #0, initialize each semaphore to the value 1.
2. In each other program, use `semop()` to wait for its semaphore to reach value 0.  For example, program #1 waits for semaphore #0's value to become 0, using `semop()`.
3. Modify each program to actually take a non-zero amount of time to do its work.  I suggest a for loop like this:

   ```
   for (int i=0;i<10;i++) {
       printf("Executing process #1, iteration #%d.\n", i);
       sleep(1);
   }
   ```
4. After each program's work loop, it releases its semaphore using `semop()`.  This causes the semaphore value to transition from 1 to 0, which allows the next program to run.  For example, program #1 releases semaphore #1, causing program #2 to be able to run.
5. Program #3 cleans up instead of releasing a semaphore.